# How can be passed a cookie from jquery to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

From example, I want to pass `$.cookie('article_id')` to PHP.

Comment: Add some more context to your question. Show a code how you try to do this on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP provides a global variable called `$_COOKIE`. This is an array with all the clients' cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Ajax** of jQuery to send the cookie from client side to server side.

Basic syntax is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your php page URL',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {data: $.cookie('article_id')},
  success: function (returnData) {
      //do what ever you want on success
  },
});
```

OR

you can directly access the cookies from PHP by useing [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) global variable.